# How to use com.facebook.Session properly?

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying use Facebook Login as authentication mechanism in my app.

I can't figure out how to use com.facebook.Session object properly.

I have Activity, Fragment inside and I have button "Login with Facebook" on that fragment.

**In button handler I have this:**

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (session != null && (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()))
{
    session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
    .setPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile"))
    .setCallback(statusCallback));
}
else 
{
    Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), this, true, statusCallback);
}
```

**This is my callback:**

```
private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();

private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        // Update session status (in TextView)
        TextView tvSessionStatus = (TextView)(getView().findViewById(R.id.tvSessionStatus));
        tvSessionStatus.setText(session.getState().toString());
    }
}
```

When I click button - I see that TextView is updated by callback and there is "OPENING" text (`tvSessionStatus.setText(session.getState().toString());`)

It never changes to "OPEN" or whatever. **What I'm doing wrong?**

Comment: Did you place the session code inside onResume?

Comment: Nope. What code? Same code as in my button handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that:

**1.** you have correctly generated the app-id with OpenSSL and declared it in your application manifest.

**2.** application package name and app-id are correctly entered on your Facebook app details page.

**3.** you have applied for the relevant permissions and received them from FB.

**4.** the access token is valid (i.e. non-null).

**5.** the session state of the access token is OPENED.

**6.** You have called [`Session.onActivityResult()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Session/#onActivityResult) in your `Activity` / `Fragment`'s `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: But I have one extra question. How I was supposed to know that I need to add that / override my onActivityResult()? Can you provide link to documentation with that?